# Create chi squared matrix with specific col and row names in R

Tags: r

I am very new to R programming and I am working on an assignment that asks me to create a matrix with 25 rows and 8000 columns, with numbers taken from a chi squared distribution with 5 degrees of freedom.

Additionally, I need to assign `rownames` to the data object as the first 25 letters of the alphabet in uppercase, followed by the same letters in lowercase (1st row would be Aa, 2nd would be Bb). The column names need to be named according to the pattern: `Variable.<column number>`. So, column 4 would be named `Variable.4` and column 5 would be named `Variable.5` and so on.

So far, I have

```
ans<-matrix(rchisq(8000,5),25, dimnames=list(letters[1:25]))
```

I'm not sure I did the chi-distribution correctly and I'm not sure how to name the rows and columns correctly. Can someone help me out?

Comment: To start, you can set the names of the matrix with `names(ans) <- paste0('Variable', '.', 1:8000)` and `rownames(ans) <- paste0(LETTERS, letters)`.

Answer (score 0):

In R, you can type `?function` in the console to look at the documentation for that function.

If we look at `?rchisq`, we see that `rchisq(n, df)` generates `n` random numbers from a chi-squared distribution with `df` degrees of freedom. If you want to fill a `25 x 8000` matrix with random numbers, you need `25 * 8000 = 200000` numbers. So use: `rchisq(20000, 5)`

Then, we put those into a `matrix`. We can specify either the number of rows or number of columns and these numbers will be put in appropriately. So use either:

```
m <- matrix(rchisq(20000, 5), nrow = 25)
m <- matrix(rchisq(20000, 5), ncol = 8000)
```

To set rownames, you can either pass them as a list of vectors to the `dimnames` argument in `matrix` (as you did), in which case the first (or only) vector will set the rownames, while the second will set the column names. Or you can set them manually using the `rownames()` function.

```
m <- matrix(rchisq(20000, 5), nrow = 25)
rownames(m) <- letters[1:25]
```

or

```
m <- matrix(rchisq(20000, 5), nrow = 25, dimnames=list(letters[1:25]))
```

To join letters together, use the `paste0` function which pastes together each corresponding element of the character vectors you pass it:

```
paste0(LETTERS, letters)
 [1] "Aa" "Bb" "Cc" "Dd" "Ee" "Ff" "Gg" "Hh" "Ii" "Jj" "Kk" "Ll" "Mm" "Nn" "Oo" "Pp" "Qq" "Rr" "Ss" "Tt" "Uu" "Vv" "Ww" "Xx" "Yy" "Zz"
```